# PHP Input Form capturing start/finish timestamps

Tags: php, forms, input, timestamp

Is there a way to capture two timestamps automatically using a simple input form?

Looking to capture the time the php page is opened or refreshed and also the time the form is submitted (I have this part working) so really looking for how to capture the 'start time'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first take a hidden feild and assign the current timestamp value when page is loaded like this.`<input type="hidden" value="<?=time();?>" name="load_time">`. and when you submit the page and in the same way take current timestamp

`$current_time=time();
 $loadTime=$_REQUEST['load_time'];`

Comment: That's great, worked. When doing the update to mysql can I take the start time away from 'load_time' to give the actual time spent in minutes? Something like   SQLVal($utime - $_POST['load_time'], "int"),

Comment: i dont know about SQLVal($utime - $_POST['load_time'], "int").But you can substract start time from load time and then simply divide by 60.@GrahamDrummond